# SoundPool stop working after some time

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I recently published game [Frog2Jump](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=si.TimKmecl_D.frog2jump) to Google Play. Now some people are complaining about sound going away after few plays (usually it works 3-5 times, then not anymore). I can't find any explanation why it doesn't work.

More details: Game and Game over menu are separate activities. When you fall into water, GameActivity launches GameOverActivity and finishes itself. When you click RETRY, it launches GameActivity and finsihes itself. One game before sound goes off completely, only one in every 2 or 3 sounds is played. Sound plays every time you jump the frog (you can download the game and try to see it yourself).

Do you have any idea why it's not working?